# Android & Eclispe - ADT is closed unexpectedly while exporting my application

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Exporting does not work for one application, after many updates, but works for the others.

Right Click the project -> Export...

The ADT is closed and gives me the error "ADT is closed unexpectedly".

I have ADT v22.0.1 on MAC OS.

Comment: Of course, I searched for other questions about the same problem. There is no one said that the ADT itself is forced to close and interrupting the exporting process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using:

1- Refresh the project

2- Project > Clean...> Clean project selected below (choose the project from the list)